# lambda function does not capture the surrounding variable

Tags: scala, lambda

**f(code: String): String** is the new code function, it takes one old code string and generates new code string.

```
def getNewCodes(oldCodes: Array[String]): Array[String] = {
        val newCodes: Array[String] = Array()
        oldCodes.foreach(code => newCodes :+ f(code)) // newCodes is not captured by the lambda function
        newCodes // returns the empty array
    }
```

I passed the lambda function to get the new code and updated it to the newCodes array. The new code array shall be returned at the end of the function. But an empty array is returned.

Seems the lambda function is not captured the `newCodes` variable, Why is that?

Comment: Because `:+` returns a new copy of the array with the element appended. It does not mutate the original array.

Comment: Also, `newCodes.forEach(...)` will do nothing on an empty array. Maybe you meant `oldCodes.forEach(...)`?

Comment: @marstran I think I should looking for a some sort of update function for Scala array

Comment: @marstran you are right, I make a mistake, fixed

Comment: I think you can just do `val newCodes = oldCodes.map(code => f(code))`

Comment: Or even `val newCodes = oldCodes map f`

Comment: @IanMcLaird Right :)

Comment: or even oldCode map f, the val newCodes is not really necessary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collecting the answers from the comments gives this solution:

```
def getNewCodes(oldCodes: Array[String]): Array[String] =
  oldCodes.map(f)
```

In practice you would usually just write this in line and not bother with a separate method, especially as it is not clear where `f` comes from.